# Shift a python dictionnary values

Tags: python, hash-map

I wrote this function today that *shift* the values of a dictionnary:

```
def shift_dict(dic, shift):
    # Save the dic length
    dic_len = len(dic)

    # Reduce the shift to the dic length
    shift = shift % dic_len

    # convert the dict to a tupple to reference by index
    list_dic = [(k,v) for k, v in dic.iteritems()]

    # Create the new shifted dict
    shifted = {
        list_dic[x][0]: list_dic[ (x - shift) % dic_len ][1]
        for x in xrange(dic_len)
    }

    return shifted
```

The idea is to keep the keys but to assign the `nth - shift` value to it.

A few examples:

```
dic = {
    'a':10,
    'b':2,
    'c':30,
    'd':4,
    'e':50,
    'f':6,
}
print dic
print shift_dict(dic, 1)
print shift_dict(dic, 4)
print shift_dict(dic, -2)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 10, 'c': 30, 'b': 2, 'e': 50, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}
{'a': 6, 'c': 10, 'b': 30, 'e': 2, 'd': 50, 'f': 4}
{'a': 2, 'c': 50, 'b': 4, 'e': 6, 'd': 10, 'f': 30}
{'a': 30, 'c': 2, 'b': 50, 'e': 4, 'd': 6, 'f': 10}
```

I find that the "create a list and then another dictionnary" is not very effective, but I couldn't think of another way to do it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The result depends on the arbitrary ordering of the dict; I'm getting a different result. Seems kind of pointless to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: First of all as @JanneKarila said if you want ordered dict you should use OrderedDict. Second this can be done much more simply.

Comment: I noticed the ordering after this, thanks for the comment. user1685095: what do you mean, can the OrderedDict simplify this?

Comment: See my answer, please.

Comment: Are you using 3.6, as it'd explain why the [dictionary is ordered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323). However you shouldn't rely on this functionality.

Comment: I don't but that's good to know though.

Comment: I think I know how to do that in fewer lines of code. Give me a few minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OrderedDict` if you want an ordered dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import islice, cycle


def shift_dict(dct, shift):
    shift %= len(dct)
    return OrderedDict(
        (k, v)
        for k, v in zip(dct.keys(), islice(cycle(dct.values()), shift, None))
    )
```

Comment: Sorry but I've just spotted that my example was pretty bad thus, this solution does not work, I'm updating the question.

Comment: @nobe4 Okay, I'll try to help